# update progressbar in android

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I am starting a thread in my activity and immediately displaying progress dialog.The method in this thread after completing its task calls other thread which calls `m_progressDialog.dismiss();` method.

This works fine but i want to implement progress bar now how does this bar fills according to completion of task in previous thread.It takes indefinite amount of time for completing its operations.

this could sound ambigious but iam ready to elaborate it further if required.

A little code snippet:

Method in first thread ends like this

```
...
runOnUiThread(m_returnRes);
}

private Runnable m_returnRes = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        m_progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Also i've tried to do it this way

```
m_progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        m_progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        m_progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        m_progressDialog.setMax(100);
        m_progressDialog.setMessage("Retrieving data..");
        m_progressDialog.show();

    Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {while(m_progressDialog.getProgress()<=100){
                Thread.sleep(500);}
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    background.start();
```

but the bar does not gets filled and gets dismissed directly after .dismiss() method is called

Answer (score 3):

Try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It handles threding for itself and has function publishprogress inside the [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) to change view content, where you could update progress bar.

Comment: I'll explore about Asynctask and c if its possible

Comment: Guys did u look the question ... i have edited it and added more code snippet

Comment: .dismiss() is intented to dismiss progressdialog. Try using [.setProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgress%28int%29)